# Service maintanance messages notification banner with a dismiss option in angular application

Tags: angular, angularjs, api

I am looking for some help. I am looking to show the service messages to the users like how we show the service in maintainence related kind of notification banner on Jira board with a dismiss option. How can I achieve the same functionality in angular application? The api will be providing me list of active messages to be shown to the users. Also active messages should be shown only for a day and then set them to expire once seen

I am trying Solutions like localstorage to save the messages in local browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service injected to your root component controller or app in order to store the API data and retrieve it from its child components, ideally when the app is first loaded.